# Which widget should be used for following design in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-custompainter

[image]

I wants to redesign my current project UI with this one which widgets should be used here to implement this Screen in flutter

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to implement this screen, however as I imagine you are new to flutter, I will help you with a semi-ready widget. I advise you to look for courses on Flutter before asking for ready-made components on StackOverFlow. This community aims to help programmers evolve their code and your question has no code.

However, I've sketched out a little code that does something similar to what you're looking for, I hope you can use this code to start your project and your flutter journey, but I also want you to watch out for more concrete programming questions.

Here goes: Try to create a file called `LoginWidget` and add this piece of code, then just call the component on your main page and that's it, you'll have something similar to what you want. Take the opportunity to browse the component and change what you want.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginWidget> createState() => _LoginWidgetState();

}

class _LoginWidgetState extends State<LoginWidget> {
  late bool _passwordIsVisible = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                children: const [
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Text(
                    'Login',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Text(
                    'Welcome back! Please enter your details.',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            SizedBox(
              width: 600,
              child: Card(
                color: Colors.white,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 50),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 300,
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          labelText: 'Email',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 5, width: 300, child: Divider(color: Colors.orange,)),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 300,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        obscureText: !_passwordIsVisible,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          labelText: 'Password',
                          suffixIcon: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              _passwordIsVisible ? Icons.lock_open : Icons.lock,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _passwordIsVisible = !_passwordIsVisible;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 5, width: 300, child: Divider(color: Colors.orange,)),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    const Text(
                      'Forgot password?',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.orange,
                        onPrimary: Colors.white,
                        minimumSize: const Size(250, 50),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: const Text('Login'),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 50),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```